# CSS background not visible when content scrolls past viewport

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-color, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a css background that is 100% height at all times regardless of content height, and when the content is long enough to create a scrollbar, the background color remains as you scroll.

No matter what combination of min-height & height I try I can't seem to get this to work properly.

When I use Tailwind's `h-screen` class it fills to the bottom of the page when the content is smaller than the viewport, but when there's a scrollbar the background disappears on the scrolled section.

I've tried various combations of `h-full` and `min-height: 100%`, on parent divs/body/html, but nothing seems to work.

Here's a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/t30wo6uk/3/

Here's screenshots of the two problems demonstrated:

`h-screen` works when there's no scrollbar, but once there's a scroll it cuts off:

[image: background cuts off with scrollbar]

If I remove `h-screen` or try combinations of `height: 100%` I get the inverse problem where it sticks when scrolling, but if the content is too small for the viewport the background color doesn't take up the full height of the page.

[image: background doesnt reach bottom]

In my real app, I have a navigation header, then this content section that I want to take up the full height, and then a sticky footer at the bottom. The sticky footer is why I have those additional divs around my content div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `min-h-screen` to the body. that will make the body at least as heigh as the viewport. Then apply the background-color to the body:

```
<body class="min-h-screen bg-gray-50">
{... content ...}
</body>
```

if the content is smaller then the viewport, `min-h-screen` will size the body to cover the entire viewport. If the content is larger, the content will determine the height. As the background-color is applied to the body, it will always cover the entire website.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding the background-color to the body because in my app I have different layouts that load depending on which page is loaded, and the layouts are nested underneath the body so don't have the ability to change the body class. Are you aware of a way to do it without adjusting the body?

Comment: you trying a SPA approach?  Then you need to include the `min-h-screen` class aswell as the `bg-` class to the element that will contain all content. Alternatively you have to use JS to add/remove classes.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue while applying Tailwind myself. For anyone still looking for an answer, `min-h-full` seemed to have worked great.