# background not fully displayed when scroll

Tags: html, css, height

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpjQO.jpg)I made min-height in body for desktop it so that the site was more adaptive and the blocks did not climb on header,and now when i make the screen smaller than 700px and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/036ro.jpg)when i scroll down, part of the image is black[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfhhP.jpg)

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS background not visible when content scrolls past viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68633173/css-background-not-visible-when-content-scrolls-past-viewport)

Comment: im already attached in this post

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that when you are adding background set its position to center and background repeat property should be set to no-repeat so that it should not repeat on large devices:

```
background: url(./path) center center/cover no-repeat;
```

Hope it will help you.